# Block site address in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I had a joomla site with standard addresses. Next I change to simple addresses. And I have problem with google robots. I had to block 2 addresses:
index.php?option=com_content&view=frontpage
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=59&Itemid=65

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The way I achieve this, rather than using .htaccess, is to configure "blocking lists" in my Apache configuration then specify which lists I want to use on various web sites.  I divided my lists into three directories called "countries", "hackers", and "robots", so I could choose what I wanted to block on a per-site basis.  Here is a sample of what one of my files looks like, with phoney IP addresses inserted:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/block-lists/hackers/na
# North American hack attempts

deny from 12.34.56.789
deny from 98.76.54.321
[etc...]
```

Then inside my Apache configuration file I can use these lists inside Directory blocks like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/ixo.ca/htdocs/main/restricted">
  Order deny,allow
  Include /etc/apache2/block-lists/countries/cn
  Include /etc/apache2/block-lists/hackers/
  Include /etc/apache2/block-lists/robots/
  </Directory>
```

This can be placed within a VirtualHost block or outside of one (e.g., in the case where you have a directory that applies to more than one site).  If you list a directory (those above ending with a slash), then all the files in that directory are included.